# How to pass data from child view of DetailViewController to MasterViewController?

Tags: uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uistoryboard, ipad

I have an iPad Storyboard-driven app that uses a split view to show a master and detail view.

The DetailViewController has a child UITableViewController, which populates a prototyped UITableView in the DetailViewController. The UITableViewController uses an NSFetchedResultsController to manage the data retrieval, for the convenience of using the data with the UITableView.

The MasterViewController contains another UITableView populated with a subset of the data contained in the UITableViewController.

The issue I have is that I need the MasterViewController to be able to update it's content from the NSFetchedResultsController record set, but have found that I can't use a delegate for this purpose, as the UITableViewController is a child of the DetailViewController, which is a child of the MasterViewController.

While I know I could use NSNotificationCenter to do this, I was hoping I could pass the relevant data back to the MasterViewController via the view hierarchy. I'd considered loading the data from the FRC into an instance variable and using KVO to trigger a delegate method on the DetailViewController, but this seems convoluted.

This is an overview of the setup at present :

`MasterViewController --> DetailViewController --> UITableViewController.NSFetchedResultsController`

Can anyone advise of the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using `NSNotification` and the method `postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`, passing the NSDictionary of values as the userInfo.
I then set my MasterViewController to listen for the notification and to process the NSDictionary to update itself.

This keeps within the programming guides set out by Apple and also allows me to pass the same information anywhere in my app.

More details here : [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use another instance of NSFetchedResultsController to provide the data to the table view in the MasterViewController.

Comment: Given that I have already fetched the data I need into memory and can enumerate it quickly to be able to generate the data required by the MasterViewController, it seems inefficient to re-retrieve all of the data again.  I am looking into using NSNotifications to pass the generated data, as I also need to send the details of the selected cell in the MasterViewController.

Comment: Just to avoid propagating a misperception regarding efficiency, I would clarify that subsequent fetch requests on a managed object context will not re-retrieve objects that are already in memory.